# printing content of a picturebox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, printdialog

HI all,

I have a picture box in my C# WinForms application which is sized 800x800. I want to print the content of this picture box using the following code but it does not do anything at all (just shows the print dialog and when I click on PRINT in the dialog it doe nothing too. What's wrong?

```
    private void menuFilePrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;
        printDocument.DocumentName = "TEST IMAGE PRINTING";

        printDialog.Document = printDocument;
        printDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(curveBox.Image, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't instruct the `printDocument` to print:

```
if(printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    printDocument.Print();
```

the [`printDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) is used to set printing settings.

Answer (score -1):

Without this command "printDocument1.Print();" Nothing will work.