# Printing a pictureBox in a MdiChild

Tags: c#, printing, picturebox, mdichild

I'm trying to print the content of a pictureBox in a MdiChild.
Debugging the code looks like it never triggers the PrintPage event.
I've mainly used this code for the project: [printing content of a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920989/printing-content-of-a-picturebox)

What is wrong ?

Here is my code:

```
private void stampaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as Form2;
        PictureBox theBox = (PictureBox)activeChild.pictureBox1;
        dastampare = theBox.Image as Bitmap;
        printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "Prova";
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dastampare, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Note: You are calling `printDialog1.ShowDialog()` twice.  If your debugger is reaching the `printDocument1.Print();` line and not your PrintPage event, then you most likely don't have the event handler wired up.

Comment: You are absolutely right LarsTech. Fixed it removing printDialog1.ShowDialog(); Still I can't trigger the PrintPage event. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form's constructor, try wiring up the eventhandler:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
}
```